# Notation for the category of categories with a lift of the Hom functor

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a category with a functor $U:\mathcal{V}\to \textbf{Set}$. I am looking for a good notation for the category of pairs $(\mathcal{C},\underline{\text{Hom}}_{\mathcal{C}})$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is a category and $\underline{\text{Hom}}_{\mathcal{C}}:\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{V}$ is a lift of $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}$, meaning $U\circ\underline{\text{Hom}}_{\mathcal{C}}=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}$.

As an example, if $\mathcal{V}=\textbf{Cat}$ and $U:\textbf{Cat}\to \textbf{Set}$ sends a category to its set of objects, then we get the category of [sesquicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sesquicategory).